# DP sum all node combinations

Tags: dynamic-programming

Given a tree and a value for each node, how can we get the total sum for each possible path?

```
  A
  |
  B
```

In the above tree there will be 4 such paths: A, B, A-B, B-A.
Each node will have a value assign to it: `A: 3, B: 2`

The expected output should be: 3+2+(3+2)+(2+3)

A naive solution for this problem is to do a DFS from source to target(for each possible combination) and get the sum by adding the DFS result, but I believe this problem can be solved more efficiently with DP, but don't really have so much experience with DP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice solution for this one which doesn't involve (much) dynamic programming:

You can compute how often each node appears in paths. Lets just take an example with `n=5` nodes:

```
    A
    |
    B
   / \
  C   D
      |
      E
```

The computation for the leaves `A`, `C` and `E` is very easy. They only appear in paths that start or end with this node. There are `2n - 1 = 9` paths (`-1` because the path `A` starts and end ends with `A` and is therefore counted twice in `2*n`).

For the inner nodes it gets a bit more tricky. Lets look at the node `D` first. Of course `D` appears in all paths, that start or end in `D`. So we again have `2n - 1 = 9` paths. But now it can also be the case that `D` appears somewhere in the middle of a path. E.g. in the path `A-B-D-E`. This can only happen, if the path starts somewhere in the subtree `ABC` and ends in the subtree `E` or opposite. Combinatorics tells us, that there are `size(ABC)*size(E) + size(E)*size(ABC) = 2*size(ABC)*size(E) = 2*3*1 = 6` many. So `D` appears in exactly `9 + 6 = 15` paths.

For node `B` it still gets a bit more tricky. There are again `2n - 1 = 9` paths starting or ending from `B` (This is true for each node). But again `B` can appear somewhere in the middle of a path. For this to happen a path must start in one of the subtrees `A`, `C` or `DE` and end in a different one. So there are `2*size(A)*size(C) + 2*size(C)*size(DE) + 2*size(DE)*size(A) = 2*1*1 + 2*1*2 + 2*2*1 = 2 + 4 + 4 = 10` possible paths. With a little bit of math you can see that this is identical to `(n-1)^2 - size(A)^2 - size(C)^2 - size(DE)^2`. So in total the node appears in `9 + 10 = 19` paths.

And the value you want to compute is `9*value(A) + 19*value(B) + 9*value(C) + 15*value(D) + 9*value(E)`.

With one depth-first-search you can compute the sizes of all subtrees with dynamic programming and compute the number of appearances for each node using the two formulas.